# Confusion on the deprecation of React Native Unimodules

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli, expo-camera, react-native-unimodules

On their documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-unimodules/

```
This library is deprecated!
As of Expo SDK 43, react-native-unimodules is deprecated in favor of the expo package. Please 
refer to the Installing Expo modules guide.
```

Currently I am using React Native Unimodules for React Native CLI with expo-camera@^11.2.2, It is working fine for my two app, but if I upgrade expo-camera to the latest ver I get the

```
Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
```

Since I am using React Native CLI, I am confused to whether I should migrate to expo-module in order to use the latest version of expo-camera or is it only for Expo CLI?

Comment: Have you followed this guide -- https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md?

Comment: oh yes, I learned that it also works on RN cli, which I tried a few days ago and it does work thanks.